# Integer factorization: comparing with floor

Tags: integers, factoring

While working on [integer factorization algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118529/integer-factorization-possible-progress) I came to the next problem:

$$\frac{a}{ex} = \lfloor{\frac{a}{ex}\rfloor} + c$$

- $a$ the number I want to factor
- $x$ factor of $a$
- $e$ positive integer that I choose

For $e = 1$ I found a linear representation for short sequences of $\lfloor{\frac{a}{x}\rfloor}$, this allows me to compare it to $\frac{a}{x}$ and find the value of $x$. The problem is that there are to many sequences, for this to be efficient. So I decrease their amount by using $e > 1$. Unfortunately it created $c$, and now I have to test all its possible values, it looks some thing like this:

- for $e=2$, $c$ can be $\frac{1}{2}$
- for $e=3$, $c$ can be $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{2}{3}$
- for $e=4$, $c$ can be $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{2}{4}$ or $\frac{3}{4}$

Is there any way that I can predict the values of $c$, or give it a better estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $c$ is given by the formula
$$ c = \frac{(a/x) \pmod{e}}{e}. $$

Comment: I doubt this answer is helpful. If it isn't, could you explain what you're actually after?

Comment: $c$ is the bottle neck of my algorithm, I want to reduce the values it may have. When factoring large numbers like 1024 bit, $e$ have to be some where at 500+ bits, it makes it very unclear to what $c$ might be.